# How to increase image resolution in openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, resolution

I have some high-resolution images, but when adding them to excel using openpyxl, their resolutions becomes low. 
My example code is here.

```
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('high_resolution_image.png')
img.anchor = AbsoluteAnchor(pos=position, ext=size)
ws.add_image(img)
```

What is the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: What Excel version are you using. If 2016 or later is it set for high fidelity images?

Comment: You'll need to create the anchor that positions the image over the worksheet yourself.